# How to add multiple conditions on Laravel elequent relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am new to Laravel and working on 5.4 version. I have a model "A" and model "B". Model A has hasMany relationship with B. Upto here things are ok. But now, I want to add more conditions on this relationship.

By default, Laravel works only foreign key relation. I mean it matches data on the basis of only 1 condition. Here, I want more condition.

Below are the tables of both Model:

table: A

```
id      name      Year  
 1      ABC       2016  
 2      DEF       2017
```

table: B

```
 id     A_id     name   Year  
  1       1      tst    2016  
  2       2      fdf    2017  
  3       1      kjg    2017
```

By default, If I want to see records of A_id 1 from table B, then Laravel will fetch all records  for A_id 1. But now, suppose, if I want to get records for 2016 then How I can I do this using Laravel relationship method?

Below are the Elequent Model for both tables:

```
class A extends Model{  

    public function b(){  
       return this->hasMany('B');  
    }  
}  


class B extends Model{  
     public function a(){  
       return $this->belongsTo('A');  
     }
}  

Code to fetch records of id 1:  

$data = A::with('b')->find(1)->toArray();
```

The above request is giving me all data from table B for id 1 but I also want to put corresponding year condition also.

Is anyone know, Ho can I do this? Please share your solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to constrain your eager loads, using an array as the parameter for `with()`, using the relationship name as the key, and a closure as the value:

```
$data = A::with([
    'b' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('year', '=', '2016');
    },
])->find(1)->toArray();
```

The closure automatically gets injected an instance of the Query Builder, which allows you to filter your eager loaded model.

The corresponding section in the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Your answer proves that, reading through documentation is a good thing...

Comment: It also helps, that I've been using Laravel for more than 2 years. :) And yes, the documentation is the best source for most of the basic problems.

Comment: Dude, I already know this solutions. But I want to make it generic. Suppose, I want to fetch all A records then each A record should have only those B records that belongs to corresponding A id as well as matches corresponding year.

Comment: Well, you can save a few characters by replacing the where clause with a scope, but it won't get any more generic than this.